# iOS attempt to insert nil object from objects'

Tags: ios, xcode, nsstring, nsarray

I have this below error

> [__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil
>   object from objects[1]

It happens everytime I try to tap on the share button in one of my product post, and only if that post has a title (defined as item_title) that contains Chinese Characters.

The function of the share button is like this

```
-(void)shareBtnTapped
{

    NSArray * activityItems = @[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[delegate attributestringtostring:[[delegate.detailPageArray objectAtIndex:delegate.detailArraySelectedIndex]objectForKey:@"item_title"]]],[NSURL URLWithString:[[delegate.detailPageArray objectAtIndex:delegate.detailArraySelectedIndex]objectForKey:@"product_url"]]];
    NSArray * applicationActivities = nil;
    NSArray * excludeActivities = @[UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeMessage];

    UIActivityViewController * activityController = [[[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:applicationActivities] autorelease];
    activityController.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities;
    [self.view.window.rootViewController presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];
    [Answers logCustomEventWithName:@"Item Page Tapped" customAttributes:@{@"Btn":@"Shared"}];

}
```

It works fine if the title is in English. I am very lost at the moment, and hoping if any experts here can shred some lights. Thank you so much.

Additional info:
the item_title is saved as utf8mb4 in the database.

Problem solved: Thank you everyone for helping out! 
Since I know it is the url issue, I make the below changes to ensure the URL is defining the Chinese Character.

```
NSString* stringURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:[[delegate.detailPageArray objectAtIndex:delegate.detailArraySelectedIndex]objectForKey:@"product_url"]];
NSString* webStringURL = [stringURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:webStringURL];



NSArray * activityItems = @[obj1, url];
```

Comment: In this line `NSArray * activityItems = ...` one of the items you are using to initialize the array is nil.

Comment: As mag_zbc said, if it's as we can guess `activityItems` creation line which is causing the crash, I'd strongly suggest to use intermediate vars, instead of this long line with imbricated instructions to find which one is nil.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will dig into this part. Hopefully, I can find the solutions and report back ! Thank you.

Comment: But then, I have a question..... it works fine if the title is in English, but returns nil when the title is in Chinese?

Comment: @Kevin probably there is no chinese string define?!

Comment: ok great then you can accept answer that helped you find out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line:

```
NSArray * activityItems = @[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[delegate attributestringtostring:[[delegate.detailPageArray objectAtIndex:delegate.detailArraySelectedIndex]objectForKey:@"item_title"]]],[NSURL URLWithString:[[delegate.detailPageArray objectAtIndex:delegate.detailArraySelectedIndex]objectForKey:@"product_url"]]];
```

One of the items you're initializing array with turns out to be nil.

Try instead

```
id item1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[delegate attributestringtostring:[[delegate.detailPageArray objectAtIndex:delegate.detailArraySelectedIndex]objectForKey:@"item_title"]]];
id item2 = [NSURL URLWithString:[[delegate.detailPageArray objectAtIndex:delegate.detailArraySelectedIndex]objectForKey:@"product_url"]];
if (item1 != nil && item2 != nil) {
    NSArray * activityItems = @[item1, item2];
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I tested and know that it is the product_url (item2) that cause the issue. Now looking into reason why the link works when the title is in english, but not when the titles in Chinese. I had it working previously, but after I set up the emoji character in mysql, then it just stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

one of your objects inserting into array is nil:

```
NSArray * activityItems = @[
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[delegate attributestringtostring:[[delegate.detailPageArray objectAtIndex:delegate.detailArraySelectedIndex]objectForKey:@"item_title"]]],
[NSURL URLWithString:[[delegate.detailPageArray objectAtIndex:delegate.detailArraySelectedIndex]objectForKey:@"product_url"]]
];
```

either its the line with NSString or line with NSURL.
you could do something like this:

```
NSString *obj1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[delegate attributestringtostring:[[delegate.detailPageArray objectAtIndex:delegate.detailArraySelectedIndex]objectForKey:@"item_title"]]];
NSURL *obj2 =  [NSURL URLWithString:[[delegate.detailPageArray objectAtIndex:delegate.detailArraySelectedIndex]objectForKey:@"product_url"]];

NSArray * activityItems = @[obj1, obj2];
```

Then put a break point at `NSArray * activityItems...` and check obj1 and obj2 in the debugger window with `po obj1` and `po obj2` if one of them says nil then you will know where the problem is. One cannot put nil in an array. so make sure your object is not nil or if nil then don't add it to array.

**edit:**

your obji1, for example, is very complex. I would check if `delegate` or `delegate.detailPageArray` or `delegate.detailArraySelectedIndex` or `objectForKey:` is not returning nil. so you can with `po` command in debugger window and check all of these objects.

Comment: That would still produce a crash if one of the items was nil

Comment: I'm trying to teach him how to catch nil object so he can later do it himself :-)

Comment: Thank you, Thank you~~ I have tested and found out that it is the product_url that returns nil. Although I am not sure why, as I can view that product page on my safari browser without problems.

Comment: Does `[delegate.detailPageArray objectAtIndex:delegate.detailArraySelectedIndex]objectForKey:@"product_url"]` returns null in case of chinese language or `[NSURL URLWithString:ofThat]` returns nil? You may need to escape them: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959383/send-http-request-with-chinese-words

Comment: I've added more explanation.